# Why can't I create a new report from a template?

Tags: reports

I am trying to create a dynamic event report from an existing standard template.  I go to Administer, click Civireports, then Create new report from template, choose Participant Report, then change all the columns and filters and get the results I need.  I rename the report from the Title tab.  I preview the report, and everything looks how I want it.  But then I have no option to save it anywhere.  Very frustrating.  Help please!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you may need to ask for (or give yourself - if you can) more permissions.

[image]